# The compilation of ocamlfind failed at "install -m 0755 ocaml-stub

Tags: bash, shell, ocaml, opam, ocamlfind

I'm new to OCaml and I'm trying to install `cohttp`. After a failure because I hadn't accepted the Xcode license agreement (OS X Sierra 10.12.6) I get an error while the package manager (opam) is trying to install a sub-dependency, `ocamlfind`.

```
=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
[ERROR] The compilation of ocamlfind failed at "install -m 0755 ocaml-stub /Users/greg/.opam/system/bin/ocaml".
Processing  1/27: [ocamlfind: rm]
#=== ERROR while installing ocamlfind.1.7.3-1 =================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           darwin
# command      install -m 0755 ocaml-stub    /Users/greg/.opam/system/bin/ocaml
# path         /Users/greg/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.7.3-1
# compiler     system (4.05.0)
# exit-code    127
# env-file     /Users/greg/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.7.3-1/ocamlfind-93888-487c34.env
# stdout-file  /Users/greg/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.7.3-1/ocamlfind-93888-487c34.out
# stderr-file  /Users/greg/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.7.3-1/ocamlfind-93888-487c34.err
```

The log files are empty. The env file has this (lightly edited):

```
PATH=/Users/greg/.opam/system/bin:/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/greg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin::/opt/chefdk/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/greg/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=/Users/greg/.opam/system/lib/toplevel
PERL5LIB=/Users/greg/.opam/system/lib/perl5:
MANPATH=/Users/greg/.opam/system/man:/Users/greg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/share/man:/usr/local/mysql/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
OPAMSWITCH=system
OPAMUTF8MSGS=1
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/greg/.opam/system/lib/stublibs:/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/fq/9ggcftcj1lsb150mldyjn5sh0000gn/T/
NVM_PATH=/Users/greg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/lib/node
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jNLKBcDJTX/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=388.1.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=E845D49D-9C60-4CEA-8777-19F521ED83A1
NVM_DIR=/Users/greg/.nvm
USER=greg
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0CA6ZcRBJQ/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x52
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
PWD=/Users/greg/dev/ocaml
EDITOR=emacs
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
NODE_PATH=./src
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
NODE_ENV=development
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
HOME=/Users/greg
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=greg
NVM_BIN=/Users/greg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin
NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://iojs.org/dist
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_tab_title
_=/usr/local/bin/opam
OPAM_PACKAGE_VERSION=1.7.3-1
OPAM_PACKAGE_NAME=ocamlfind
MAKELEVEL=
MAKEFLAGS=
```

I don't have a lot to go on to debug this. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This github issue for `opam` led me to a solution that worked for me: https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/10064

The solution to the github issue was that the user had the local directory, `.`, in their `$PATH` which led to the wrong `install` command being run. This wasn't my problem, but I had an extra `:` in my path.

```
/Users/greg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.5.0/bin::/opt/chefdk/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

According to the comment below having two colons in a row in the path string will add the empty string as part of the path which is interpreted as the current directory.

Removing the extra colon allows the install of `ocamlfind` to succeed.

Comment: Yes, two colons adds the directory with an empty name ("") to the path, which is (vacuously) the name of the current directory.